# Why I can't change font size for label?

Tags: html, css

I have little problem and don't know why it doesn't work. I tried to change font size for label tag, but I can't set less than 10px. Why?

```css
.group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.group label {
  font-size: 10px;
}
.group2 label {
  font-size: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <label for="input1">First label</label>
  <input type="text" name="input1">
</div>
<div class="group group2">
  <label for="input2">Second label</label>
  <input type="text" name="input2">
</div>
```

Comment: it's working perfectly in snippet..

Comment: if you are using chrome you may want to hard refresh your browser with: Cmd/Shift/R on mac and Cntrl/Shift/R on windows. Since chrome caches the page your changes might not be visible yet

Comment: I'm using Opera and website is on localhost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested this one on my side and it works as intended.

If you are loading the styles via a stylesheet it is possible that your browser has cached this, and you may need to clear browser caches.

Some browsers do also supply default values for most HTML elements. (Something to consider)

Comment: But on localhost I have to clear cache too? I thought only when I have website on server I have to do it.

Comment: As this is browser caching you will need to clear your browser cache. Or simply view it incognito. Browser cache does affect localhost

Comment: Oh, really I had to only clear cache in my browser. Thanks.

Comment: My pleasure, glad to hear that helped!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** It turned out that cached *CSS* in *Opera* was responsible non-updating styling.

Working as required. Remember to re-run your code snippet after making changes.

```css
.group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.group label {
  font-size: 10px;
}
.group2 label {
  font-size: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <label for="input1">First label</label>
  <input type="text" name="input1">
</div>
<div class="group group2">
  <label for="input2">Second label</label>
  <input type="text" name="input2">
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, but I don't see any differences between 10px and 4px, look at screen with your code demo: http://i.imgur.com/popRTSw.png

Comment: What browser are you running it on? Maybe, try to clear the cache of your browser? It should be working all good.

Comment: I'm using Opera and website is on localhost but yes, clear the cache and everything  works fine :)